# Android RatingBar problem in device

Tags: android, rating

Hi I am using Rating Bar in my App. When I try it in emulator the rating bar is fully visible. (i.e) I am able to see all the five stars, but when I try it in my droid mobile, I am able to see only four stars. Can anyone suggest me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be because of a totally different situation.

The Default star of the Rating Bar doesn't reduce their size to adjust the layout. What ever is the screen size it has the same size(Big, small etc). So if we set the Star size to big, it will just make the star to hide from the layout. So the best solution is to make the layout size enough to fit the number of stars you are about to provide.

If not provide small style star to your Rating Bar if your layout can't accomadate big star style.

Answer (score 1):

This can be layout issue. In droid mobile if your layout is not able to stretch properly , and you have specified certain width to rating bar, stars(layout) gets truncated. Arrange layouts using layout weights, that might solve your problem.

Comment: Can you tell me the value that I am supposed to give for layout weight

Comment: That depends on your layout design. You will have to understand how layout weight works and its a simple concept.

Comment: Can you please help? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: search for layout_weights in this, http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts , one will understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any padding on the RatingBar element? I just had a similar clipping issue when layout_width of my RatingBar was set to wrap_content and I had paddin_left and padding_right defined.

Removing the padding removed the clipping